# Clonezilla - What is going on when it says 'Syncing...'

Tags: clonezilla

I have booted clonezilla live done a partition-to-partition copy to copy between a 5400rpm HDD into unpartitioned space on a new SSD (both connected via sata).

It took over 12.5 hours to copy 100GB. The 'remaining' time only ever went up (not down). Why is the rate that low when they are both connected onto the primary sata 3 bus?

[image]

Now it is sitting on 100% and has been for a further 6 hours. I'm just wondering what it is "syncing" about. The time remaining is zero; the elapsed isn't changing. The cursor is still blinking away; the mouse moves, so it doesn't appear to be a lockup. What does this part of the process do?

[image]

how long do I leave it before I pronounce it a fail, if it indeed is one?